# Type mismatch: cannot convert from "sth" to "sth"

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
public class ListCollection<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private int size;
    private ListNode<T> first;
    private ListNode<T> last;
    ...

private class ListNode<E> {
    private ListNode<E> next;
    private ListNode<E> previous;
    private E value;

    public ListNode() {
        super();
    }
}
private class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        ListNode<T> next, previous;

        public ListIterator() {
            next = first;
        }
```

I want to initialize iterator. In line next = first I get error message.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ListCollection.ListNode to ListCollection.ListNode

Why? How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
private class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
```

to

```
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<T>
```

otherwise the type parameter T used by `ListIterator<T>` won't be the same type parameter T declare in `ListCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code likewise, i.e. Integer,

```
private int size;
private ListNode<Integer> first;


private class ListNode<E> {
    private ListNode<E> next;
    private ListNode<E> previous;
    private E value;

    public ListNode() {
        super();
    }
}

private class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

        ListNode<Integer> next, previous;

        public ListIterator() {
            next = first;
        }
    }
}
```